# how can i get rid of this small logical error?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a small GUI application where both the user and the computer are clicking the button widget turn by turn.

First, the user Click the Button and the Button text changes, then the computer clicks the button and the different texts appear on the button for the machine

Here's the code.

```
from tkinter import *

globals()['status'] = True

class test11(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('200x200')

        self.btn_1 = Button(self,text="CLICK ME",command=lambda :self.test_function(1,2))
        self.btn_1.grid()

        if not (globals()['status']):
            self.machine()

    def test_function(self,aa,bb):
        self.btn_1['text'] = f'Dont CLICK ME {aa} {bb} HUMAN'
        globals()['status'] = False

    def machine(self):
        self.btn_1['text'] = f'Computer just clicked me'
        globals()['status'] = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = test11()
    a.mainloop()
```

But the problem is the turn of the machine never comes even though the user has already pressed the button.

As the user presses the button the values of global variable changes which should have let the machine function to call isn't it?

Comment: You can just call `self.machine()` inside `test_function()`.  You can use `after()` to delay the call to simulate that the machine is thinking.  Actually `globals()['status']` is not necessary and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much, now feel like an idiot for missing out such simple logic. Anyways Thanks for answering